# The snap version of gedit won't let me save files. How can I fix this?

Tags: permissions, snap, gedit

### EDIT

**This question can be closed, because it's [being looked at](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/classic-request-for-gedit/20235) by the snap team.**

---

gedit version 3.36.2 [has a bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/issues/361) that causes me formatting problems (it affects many files of mine, so there's no easy workaround).

Curiously, the snap version doesn't have this problem.
So, obviously, I want to use the snap version of gedit.

But.

The snap version of gedit won't allow me to save a file, whether it's a new file or an edited file. EDIT: It allows me to save files in some of my folders, but not all of them, e.g. `~/bin` and `~/insurance`.

EDIT: I can't even edit standard items such as `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`. And I can't edit system files, e.g. `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`.

I have followed the instructions to add the requisite permissions to the snap from Software. Several settings were already on, including "Access files in your home folder", so for good measure, I gave permission to everything. See the attached screenshot. I've even tried restarting the computer to see if that makes a difference, which of course it doesn't.

I've also tried installing in classic mode, but I receive a warning showing that it won't do so:

```
$ snap install --classic gedit
Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap gedit
```

I should add that the files in question are all within subdirectories of my home folder (/home/paddy), and everything has read-write permission for my user.

I have been searching and searching, and I simply cannot find a solution to this.

How can I give the snap version of gedit permission to write files?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 (a recent fresh installation) with Gnome 3.36.3 and gedit version 3.36.2.

Thank you

[image: Snap permissions for gedit in Software]

Comment: That is an example where snaps currently are seriously flawed. The home interface only allows you to save in the XDG directories listed in the left pane, nowhere else under your own home. You should try `flatpak`. It is a lot better for desktop applications, and also with the theming.

Comment: @vanadium — Thank you. I'd like to see the list of the XDG directories, but I don't know what you mean by "the left pane"; where is this pane? Unfortunately, the flatpak version has the same bug, so it's really the snap that I need.

Comment: I was referring to the left pane in Files or in a file open dialog: "Documents", "Pictures", etc.

Comment: Thank you, @vanadium. I've fixed some of the folders, e.g. `~/bin`, by moving them into `~/Documents` and then creating a symbolic link. But some of them can't be fixed in this way, e.g. files that I have to access outside of my home folder (yet are still owned by me), and system files, e.g. `/etc/fstab`.